# SQL select only one item which meets condition

Tags: sql, dashdb

I have a very narrow table: DATA, ID, LAT, LNG, TIME.
(https://gyazo.com/52b268c00963ed12ba85c6765f40bf63)

And I want to select the newest data for each different ID. I was using query like

```
SELECT * 
  FROM name_of_table 
 WHERE TIME > my_given_time;
```

but it selects TOTALLY all datas and not only data for each different id which meets the condition.

Could somebody please help me write the query?

Thank you for any help. :)

**EDIT**

The final look of my working query looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TIME DESC) AS ROWNUMBER, * FROM my_table) WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1) WHERE TIME > my_time;
```

Thanks everyone for help

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @Strawberry I use DashDB on Bluemix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about something like this

```
SELECT ID, DATA 
FROM (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY TIME DESC) AS ROWNUMBER, ID, DATA
 FROM name_of_table)
WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1;
```

For these dummy records

```
INSERT INTO name_of_table (ID, TIME, DATA) VALUES('test',1230,16);
INSERT INTO name_of_table (ID, TIME, DATA) VALUES('test2',1235,10);
INSERT INTO name_of_table (ID, TIME, DATA) VALUES('test',1234,20);
```

the query returns the data value for the largest timestamp for each ID

```
  ID    DATA
  ----- ----
  test    20
  test2   10
```

Comment: It almost works as i wanted! I just little modified your query (viz. edit). Thanks <3

Comment: Glad it helped you find a solution that works for you! Note that there's really no need for your outermost SELECT to filter by time. Consider changing the condition "WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1"  to "WHERE ROWNUMBER = 1 AND TIME > my_given_time" instead to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM `sometable` a
JOIN (SELECT MAX(TIME) AS `max_time`,`ID` FROM `sometable` group by `ID`) b
ON b.`ID` = a.`ID` AND a.`TIME` = b.`max_time`;
```

Comment: @SloanThrasher I don't know if i am writing this wrong. So everything in ' ' i should replace with my own "variables"?

Comment: Not variables, but column and table names for the back tics,

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
SELECT tt.* FROM tblTest tt
WHERE _ID IN (
    SELECT TOP 1 _ID FROM tblTest WHERE ID = tt.ID ORDER BY TIME DESC
)
```

Assuming _ID that i found in your linked picture is a unique identifier for each individual row

Comment: I copied it and by DB threw an error : **Error occurred processing a conditional compilation directive near "_". Reason code="7".  SQLSTATE=428HV**